# How to add IconTabSeparator in items template?

Tags: sapui5, tabbar

I have a SAPUI5 app with JSON view. Below is the code for JSON view

```
"sections": [
  {
    "id": "idMenuButtonSection",
    "subSections": [
      {
        "main": [
          {
            "Type": "sap.m.IconTabBar",
            "headerMode": "Inline",
            "headerBackgroundDesign": "{widgetModel>/headerBackgroundDesign}",
            "items": [
              {
                "path": "widgetModel>/filters",
                "template": {
                  "Type": "sap.m.IconTabFilter",
                  "showAll": "{widgetModel>showAll}",
                  "enabled": "{widgetModel>enabled}",
                  "text": "{widgetModel>text}",
                  "icon": "{widgetModel>icon}",
                  "iconColor": "{widgetModel>color}",
                  "count": "{widgetModel>count}",
                  "content": [
                    {
                      "Type": "sap.m.Button",
                      "text": "{widgetModel>text}"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]}
```

And I want to add one more aggregation that is `IconTabSeparator`. How do I add that?

Is it possible to send that separator in JSON view while I am using a template? should I add that separator in the controller?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by extending the existing control (sap.m.IconTabBar). I added one property in metadata that is separator and in event delegation `onBeforeRendering` I have added following code

```
                    let items = this.getAggregation('items');
                    let itemsLength = items.length - 1,
                        j = 1;
                    if (itemsLength > 0) {
                        for (let i = 0; i < itemsLength; i++) {
                            this.insertAggregation('items',
                                new sap.m.IconTabSeparator({ icon: this.getSeparator() }),
                                j, true);
                            j = j + 2;
                        }
                    }
```